# Tricky design excercise

Tags: php

Hello fellow programmers.
I am a little bit confused on how to solve this problem in an elegant solution.
This is an excercise from a book I am studying but there is no solution on it.
Appreciate any help on how address this problem. Here it is:

Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100

For multiples of three print "Hello" instead of the number.
For multiples of five print "World".
For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "HelloWorld".

Thanks for your help

```
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++){
echo $i;
if(multiple_three($i) && multiple_five($i)) echo 'HelloWorld';
else{
    if(multiple_three($i)) echo 'Hello';
    if(multiple_five($i)) echo 'World';
 }
}

function multiple_three($i)
{
    if($i % 3 == 0) return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

function multiple_five($i)
{
    if($i % 5 == 0) return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

I came up with these simple solution but I still havent address the problem that I need to write the words instead of the number. In this code the number is written in any case

Comment: Seriously? There's nothing tricky there. What have you tried?

Comment: try if else statement...

Comment: Don't even need an `else`. One `for`, two `if`s. The only thing the OP might be missing is the "modulo" operator (`%` in many languages).

Comment: I tried the if else statement successfully, but that was not what I was looking for. There must be an elegant solution applying some design pattern

Comment: a for loop, some if-else statements and the modulo operator (`%` in many C like languagues) should be all you need.

Comment: @DanieleAnzelmi `There must be an elegant solution applying some design pattern` Really?  One well-meant tip: KISS is probably the single most underutilized pattern there is, and IMO the only one that's really applicable here.

Comment: @fvu I think because with the if-else I got a little bit stuck

Comment: @DanieleAnzelmi then show us some code.  Trust me, nothing tricky here, and most certainly no fancy pattern stuff, just basic logic.

Comment: @miindlek I am studying, thanks for your helpful comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not treating the tests in the right order, and you're always printing the number without any test.  Based on your explanation, the logic should be like this:

- if number is a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 5, then print HelloWorld
- else, if it's a multiple of 3, print Hello.
- else, if it's a multiple of 5 print World.
- if none of these conditions are satisfied, print the number.

Well, the code looks exactly like the explanation above

```
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++){
    if(multiple_three($i) && multiple_five($i)) {
        echo "HelloWorld\n";
    } else if (multiple_three($i)) {
        echo "Hello\n";
    } else if(multiple_five($i)) {
        echo "World\n";
    } else {
        echo $i . "\n";
    }
}
```

I also added some line breaks to improve the output.  Output looks like this:

```
1
2
Hello
4
World
Hello
7
8
Hello
World
11
Hello
13
14
HelloWorld
16
...
```

Test it online here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5adc36408c3067a93a75c20aa71d2aad510d6eba

EDIT (tongue in cheek):  well, it can be done without explicit if/else, like this

```
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++){
  echo ($i%15?$i%5?$i%3?$i:"World":"Hello":"HelloWorld")."\n";
}
```

But I have some remarks here:

- I said "explicit" because the ternary operation is an if/else in disguise
- you'll probably agree with me that the readability suffered a bit
- this code should be considered as an exercise in terseness, if you produce such a line in a production context you should expect lots of deserved hate from your colleagues

:)

Comment: Thanks fvu. I guess I just tried to complicate the things in my mind. Lesson learned, keep it simple

Comment: @DanieleAnzelmi you're welcome.   I added a slightly absurd way of "avoiding" the if-else construct.  I think you'll agree that although it's pretty compact, it's a disaster to read.  Remember the KISS rule, it's oh so easy to forget.